# How can i set the value of a hidden field after successful ajax post?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I've got some code that works nicely for saving to the database etc. What i'd like to do now is after the fields are saved, i want the echoed last id to be populated to a hidden field so i can use that to determine any future insert/update queries.

My form is:

```
<div id="formHolder">
<form type="post" action="add_room.php" id="mainForm">
    <label for="itemName[]">Item</label>
    <input type="text" name="itemName[]">
    <label for="itemPhoto[]">Item</label>
    <input type="text" name="itemPhoto[]">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenId[]" value="">
    <div class="save">Save Item</div>
</form>
</div>
```

my jQuery is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').on('click', '.save', function(e) {
            var string = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "add_room.php",
                data: string,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    $('#message').text('The id of the inserted information is ' + data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#addForm').on('click', function(){
            $('<form><label for="itemName[]">Item</label><input type="text" name="itemName[]"><label for="itemPhoto[]">Photo</label><input type="text" name="itemPhoto[]"><input type="hidden" name="hiddenId[]" value=""><div class="save">Save Item</div></form>').fadeIn(500).appendTo('#formHolder');
        });
    });
</script>
```

and finally my php is:

```
<?PHP

    include('dbConfig.php');

    $item = $_POST['itemName'];
    $photo = $_POST['itemPhoto'];

    foreach($item as $key => $val) {

        if ($stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT test (test_title, test_desc) VALUES (?, ?)"))
        {
            // Use an s per variable passed to the string, example - "ss", $firstname, $lastname
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $val, $photo[$key]);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

            echo $db->insert_id;
            //echo "success";
        }
        // show an error if the query has an error
        else
        {
            echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
        }
    }

?>
```

Everything works nicely for adding field data to the database, adding extra fields etc. I just cannot get it to save the echoed id of each ajax post to save to the hidden field, yet it saves it to the #message div no problem. Any ideas? I have tried using .val(); but it didn't work, i'm stumped

Andy

Answer (score 5):

try this within success function

```
$("[type=hidden]").val(data);
```

or if you able to set the hidden field id thats much better like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenId[]" id="hiddenId" value="">
```

code will be like this

```
 $("#hiddenID").val(data);
```

Hope it will help

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. I have the code - 
    success: function(data){
        $('#message').text('The id of the inserted information is ' + data);
    }
Now, because i am using $(this) to submit the form that is closest to the .save div i need it to only update THAT hidden field only. So would i do something like?
success: function(data){
        $(this).closest("[type=hidden]).val(data);
    }

Comment: i have asked for your response on the above code, i need to know if it will work. It needs to display this returned id in the hidden field for sure. I can't accept an answer if it won't work fully the way i need

Comment: one more think as you set $(this) it will not work in success function

Comment: how would i get around this then? Quite a key aspect haha

Comment: you need to set like this $this = $(this); before success(after $(this).closest('form').serialize();) after that you  need in sucess function like : $this.closest("[type=hidden]).val(data);

Comment: how u doing ? follow the above comment I Just mentioned these steps

Comment: I've looked at your code, and you have put an id on the hidden field. I cannot use an id as there are going to be more and it needs to target the one that has been closest to the .save that has been clicked, hence the need to use $(this), which isnt working

Comment: so you can use like this $this.closest('[type=hidden]').val(data)

Comment: Yes, but it isn't working which is what i'm trying to say. If you update the code again with what you just said i will try it again on my machine. But so far, no luck

Comment: $this.closest('[type=hidden]').val(data); you can use like $this.prev().val(data);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
$("[type=hidden").val(data);
```

or

```
$("#hiddenId").attr("value",data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` variable in the ajax success function contains all output from your php file so if you are adding multiple items, it will be a string with all newly added ID's concatenated together.

What I would do is something like:

- use a counter in the html form-fields so that you know exactly what fields to address, something like: `<input type="text" name="itemName[1]">`;
- add this key and the value to an array in your php instead of echoing it out: `$array[$key] = $db->insert_id;`;
- after your php insert loop, echo out the data you need on the javascript side: `echo json_encode($array);`
- loop through your data in the ajax success function to assign the right values to the right elements.

You'd probably need to change your ajax call a bit to accept json.

Comment: As each form is seperate, my current code works as it should and sends the right values to the database etc. Getting the id is the only bit i am having issues on. I am new to this so would you be able to post a code example?

Comment: I want to be able to use the id to determine if a set of fields should be updated(id exists) or inserted as new items if there is no id :)

Comment: If each form is separate, why are you using arrays in your form field names and a loop in your php?

Comment: Because for some reason this is the only way my php would process the data sent to it. When i removed the loop and the arrays it would only work on the first form, despite more being added

Comment: I have a feeling i need to recode this again. If you can fully explain how i can grab the id and pop it in i can try later :)